# Make the Camera fit the background image in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

Okay so I have a long image I'm using for a scene, it will be the entire level 1 background.

The height is 1080. I set the render settings to the same as my background image, but the camera has the Default unity background showing at the bottom of my floor (bottom of sprite image background).

If I move the camera it doesn't do anything about the black background.

I'm also using a script on the camera to follow the player, could that be an issue?

Sorry if I wasn't that clear here is screen cap:

http://s30.postimg.org/4aq7hd4a9/EXAMPLE.jpg

and here is what I'd like it to look like:

http://s17.postimg.org/r2pgy8pnz/example_2.jpg

Here is the camera script:

```cs
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameCamera : MonoBehaviour {

    private Transform target;
    private float trackSpeed = 10;


    // Set target
    public void SetTarget(Transform t) {
        target = t;
    }

    // Track target
    void LateUpdate() {
        if (target) {
            float x = IncrementTowards(transform.position.x, target.position.x, trackSpeed);
            float y = IncrementTowards(transform.position.y, target.position.y, trackSpeed);
            transform.position = new Vector3(x,y, transform.position.z);
        }
    }

    // Increase n towards target by speed
    private float IncrementTowards(float n, float target, float a) {
        if (n == target) {
            return n;   
        }
        else {
            float dir = Mathf.Sign(target - n); // must n be increased or decreased to get closer to target
            n += a * Time.deltaTime * dir;
            return (dir == Mathf.Sign(target-n))? n: target; // if n has now passed target then return target, otherwise return n
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If i turn off the script for the camera to follow the player .. The player just drops to the bottom the camera does not move . and it just stays on the sky . i can upload the script if you would like to look it over . i would really appreciate it

Comment: 0,0,0 even if i move it the background image , the unity default background still is in the same place

Comment: Here is a screen cap of my camera settings . tried to turn w to 0 but background disapeared ?? http://s28.postimg.org/h2yf9c5al/example_3.png

Comment: Camera settings seem fine. Try editing your post and adding in the GameCamera script

Comment: Okay updated with the camera script .  thanks for coming back and helping out formic.   Been banging my head all day over this